# Каким образом создается подобное?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу реализовать подобное, как на сайте `http://platinum-garage.ru/` , а точнее смену изображений при ховер на маркеры. Нужно это для будущей реализации вот такого калькулятора `https://chameleon-spb.ru/zashita-plenka.html` . Если есть люди, кто может подсказать в какую сторону копать для реализации, то спасибо заранее за ответы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там всё предельно просто - есть объекты расставленные по местам, по ховеру на них JS меняет картинку фона(тупо заменяет картинку, не больше, не меньше по событию mouseover) и при событии mouseout оно возвращает фон по умолчанию....мило, но не адаптив, и сильно делает зависимым ресурс от скорости интернета.

Comment: То есть меняет картинку целиком? Ого, ресурсозатратненько. Спасибо за ответ) Думаю, может плагин сделать для подобного, последнее время часто встречал подобное. Но вот раз такие ограничения, то стоит ли оно того? А если по медиа запросу подставлять картинки меньшего размера?